# "Error in MERN Stack Workout Tracker App with React Context: Frontend Issue with Fetching Data"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I am currently developing my first MERN stack application, which is a workout tracker. Initially, the development process was smooth until I introduced React context into the application, which caused unexpected issues. Prior to implementing the context, the form submission functionality was working correctly, and new workout data was successfully added to the database. However, after adding the WorkoutContext.js file, the custom hook useWorkoutsContext.js, and making corresponding modifications to the Home.js file, I started encountering frontend errors despite the console displaying the successful fetching of data from the backend.

Here is the link to my GitHub repo if it would help {Keep in mind that this repo contains everything to the point of using the form to add the workout, hence no trouble}:

Below you could find the 3 files that concern the error:

// WorkoutContext.js file:

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
export const WorkoutsContext = createContext();
export const workoutsReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      // This case is to set all the workouts, which also means that we're fetching all the workouts.  
      case "SET_WORKOUTS":
        return { workouts: action.payload };
      // This case is to add a workout, which also means that we're creating a workout.
      case "CREATE_WORKOUT":
        return { workouts: [action.payload, ...state.workouts] };
      default:
        return state;
    }
};
export const WorkoutsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // The 2 arguments passed to useReducer are the reducer function's name and the initial state.
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(workoutsReducer, { workouts: [] });

  return (
    <WorkoutsContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      { children }
    </WorkoutsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

// useWorkoutsContext.js:

```
import { WorkoutsContext } from "../context/WorkoutContext";
import { useContext } from "react";

export const useWorkoutsContext = () => {
    const context = useContext(WorkoutsContext);
    if (!context) {
        throw Error(
            "useWorkoutsContext must be used within a WorkoutsContextProvider"
        );
    }
    return context;
}
```

// Home.js:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import WorkoutDetails from "../components/WorkoutDetails";
import WorkoutForm from "../components/WorkoutForm";
import { useWorkoutsContext } from "../hooks/useWorkoutsContext";

const Home = () => {
  const { workouts, dispatch } = useWorkoutsContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWorkouts = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("/api/workouts");
        const data = await res.json();
        if (res.ok) {
          dispatch({ type: "SET_WORKOUTS", payload: data });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching workouts:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchWorkouts();
  }, [dispatch]);

  if (!workouts) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="workouts">
        {workouts.map((workout) => (
          <WorkoutDetails key={workout._id} workout={workout} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <WorkoutForm />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```